# Do 3D Printers Prefer Particular Topology?

Tags: 3d-models

Do 3D printers prefer particular topology?  In case I'm not using the word quite right, I'm specifically wondering if I should make the faces in my models:

1. triangles
2. quads
3. n-gons..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common file format in 3D printing is [STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)). This file format is using triangles only so when you export an object from your CAD application to STL then exporter has to transform all n-gon faces into triangles.

Once the file is created then it is usually imported by slicer application (or module) which performs slicing using [polynomial calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation) to find intersection with next surfaces. Here is [good example](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsclipper/) of such intersection finding in javascript.

So answering your question:

- no - it doesn't matter as you usually use file format in which faces are triangles but
- yes - it matters as all your n-gon faces needs to be transformed into triangles